# How do I stop the default walking animation in Roblox?

Tags: roblox

I want to anchor the primary part, to immobilize the player, but if I anchor it while they are walking, it will play the walking animation even if they release the walk key. How do I pause/stop the default walking animation?

Answer (score 0):

To immobilize the player you could suspend the controls, like this:

```
controls = require(game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerScripts:WaitForChild("PlayerModule")):GetControls()

wait(5)

--suspending controls for 5 seconds:
controls:Disable()
wait(5)

--resuming controls
controls:Enable()
```